# file_put_contents in framework/views failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, laravel, centos, vps

> file_put_contents(/home/gbtire/domains/site/public_html/gb-tire/storage/framework/Views/74f95f98511096a7aa6ab74d75b8f13a61b7b1d3.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

in vps centos i run any command

```
php artisan cache:clear 
php artisan cashe:clear
```

and set any permission not work

Comment: i try that not work

Comment: Change the permissions recursive to something more opened, ex `chmod 777 -R /home/gbtire/domains/site/public_html/gb-tire/storage/framework` or make the application's user the owner of the folder

Answer (score 2):

Try: `php artisan view:clear` to clear your views cache.

Comment: i try that not work